# Downloading a blob (type: image) from a mssql db in zend framework

Tags: php, sql-server, zend-framework, zend-server

How do I do it? I've tried to use file_put_contents(), but it created a corrupted file.

I'm now trying to set up a view with the correct headers to get this working.

```
<?php   
    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64');
    echo $this->dokument->Dokument;
```

this is the content of my controller:

```
public function imageAction()
{   
    $id = $this->_getParam('id'); 

    $dokumentTabell = new Ordre_Model_Table_OrdreDokument();
    $dokument = $dokumentTabell->find($id)->current();
    $this->view->dokument = $dokument;

    // disable layout and view
    $this->view->layout()->disableLayout();
}
```

After editing it according to the first answer here, it gives this error message:  PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function setHttpResponseCode() on a non-object in ...\application\modules\ordre\controllers\OrdreController.php on line 45

line 45 is this:

```
     ->setHttpResponseCode(200)
```

The rest of the code:

```
public function imageAction()
{   
$id = $this->_getParam('id'); 

$dokumentTabell = new Ordre_Model_Table_OrdreDokument();
$dokument = $dokumentTabell->find($id)->current();
$this->view->dokument = $dokument;
$filename = $dokument->Name.".".$dokument->FileExtension;
// disable layout and view
$this->view->layout()->disableLayout();
$this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);

$this->getResponse()
     ->clearAllHeaders()
     ->clearBody()
     ->setHttpResponseCode(200)
     ->setHeader('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg')
     ->setHeader('Content-Length', strlen($dokument->Dokument))
     ->setHeader(
        'Content-Disposition',
        "attachment;filename=\"{$filename}\""
     )
     ->setHeader('Last-Modified', $dokument->SistEndret)
     ->setBody($dokument->Dokument);
}
```

If I remove line 44: ->clearBody(), the code "works". I get a file with the right name and approximately the right size.

Comment: Why are you sending base64 encoded data? Is it really base64 encoded?

Comment: It's not, just the last thing I tried. I get a corrupted file about the same size as it should have been.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, views should never output headers.. To me, it feels much more like a controller thing to do. Also, in the controller you have access to the response object, which has methods for setting headers.

Also, is `$dokument->Dokument` base64-encoded? Otherwise, just skip that header.

I'd probably do something like:

```
public function imageAction()
{   
    $id = $this->_getParam('id'); 

    $dokumentTabell = new Ordre_Model_Table_OrdreDokument();
    $dokument = $dokumentTabell->find($id)->current();
    $this->view->dokument = $dokument;

    // disable layout and view
    $this->_helper->Layout()->disableLayout();
    $this->_helper->ViewRenderer->setNeverRender();

    $this->getResponse()
         ->clearAllHeaders()
         ->clearBody()
         ->setHttpResponseCode(200)
         ->setHeader('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg')
         ->setHeader('Content-Length', strlen($dokument->Dokument))
         ->setHeader(
            'Content-Disposition',
            "attachment;filename=\"{$dokument->filename}\""
         )
         ->setHeader('Last-Modified', $dokument->lastModified)
         ->setBody($dokument->Dokument);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the very quick reply!

It only gave me an internal server error though :(

This is my code with the fields updated to correspond with the DB I'm working with (damn them for not just saving the files on a fileserver...):

Comment: [05-Jan-2011 22:22:18] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function _() on a non-object in ...\application\views\scripts\error\error.phtml on line 1

Comment: [05-Jan-2011 22:42:59] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function setHttpResponseCode() on a non-object in ...\application\modules\ordre\controllers\OrdreController.php on line 45

Line 45 is: ->setHttpResponseCode(200)

Comment: If I remove line 44: ->clearBody(), the image is downloaded, but cannot be read.

Comment: Just found out that the blob was compressed, have to find out how to decompress it.